# Can I do a domainwide installation of a gmail addon?

Tags: gmail-addons

New to the gmail addon (and addon in general)

I am thinking of building a gmail addon which will allow the domain admins to do a domainwide install of gmail addon so that it can appear in the "G Suite Marketplace".

However when I access the documentation "Admins of a G Suite domain can install and authorize a Docs, Sheets, or Forms add-on for all users in the domain if the add-on is published to the G Suite Marketplace using the instructions below".

Is a domain wide install of a gmail addon actually possible ? I may be missing something here.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can do domain wide installation by using the option "private add ons", for more information see: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish